# How do I populate a form array in Angular 2?

Tags: javascript, forms, angular

Suppose we have a form that can contain an array of values.
For this case Angular provides us with [`FormArray`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/FormArray-class.html) class.

```
this.form = new FormGroup({
  addresses: new FormArray([]),
})
```

Also we have an ability to use [`NgForm#setValue`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/NgForm-directive.html#!#setValue-anchor). This can be used i.e. to populate the form with some data retrieved from server.

When I receive new data from the server, I want to populate the form with that data. For example, my data looks like this:

```
const data = {
  addresses: [
    { country: 'USA', city: 'New York' },
    { country: 'Germany', city: 'Berlin' },
  ]
}
```

Now it's time to populate the form with this data.
When I try to simply invoke `this.form.setValue(data)` I get an error:

```
Cannot set property stack of [object Object] which has only a getter
```

How do I populate the form with data, but with these requirements:

1. I know the shape of `addresses` property.
2. I don't know the quantity of addresses in that `data.addresses` array.

Comment: Did you found a solution to this? the problem here i think is the quantity of items

Comment: @kaseOga yes, exactly! But the problem is not solved for me. I don't know how to describe a generic array interface and apply it to dynamic list of elements

Comment: @Girafa. Do you still need help with this question?

Comment: @AngularChef yes please

Answer (score 0):

Try like this below

```
this.form.setControl('addresses', this.formBuilder.array(this.data.addresses || []));
```